# Does terraform guarantee that if no changes were reported by plan, it will be able to recreate resources the same way they currently are?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a lot of resources in my Azure subscription. I want to manage them with terraform, so I want to import them using `terraform import`. I import every resource manually one-by-one. Then I run `terraform plan` and check that there are no changes to be made reported i.e. that the current infrastructure matches the configuration.

Does this mean that if I were to manually delete some of the resources via Azure portal or cli, I would be able to recreate them wit `terraform apply` perfectly so that they would have exactly the same configuration as before and would operate in exactly the same way?

Comment: No. Resources will have different IDs, and depending what you are deleting, you can delete entire databases if you have some. Apply will not re-create your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Terraform *cannot* guarantee that destroying an object and recreating it will produce an exactly equivalent object.

It is possible for that to work, but it requires a number of things to be true, including:

1. Your configuration specifies the values for resource arguments exactly as they are in the remote API. For example, if a particular resource type has a case-insensitive (but case-preserving) name then a provider will typically ignore differences in case when planning changes but it will use exactly the case you wrote in the configuration, potentially selecting a different name.
2. The resource type does not include any "write-only" arguments. Some resource types have arguments that are used only by the provider itself and so they don't get saved as part of the object in the remote API even though they are saved in the Terraform state. `terraform import` therefore cannot re-populate those into the state, because there is nowhere else to read them from except the Terraform state.
3. The provider doesn't have any situations where it treats an omitted argument as "ignore the value in the remote system" instead of "unset the value in the remote system". Some providers make special exceptions for certain arguments where leaving them unset allows them to "drift" in the remote API without Terraform repairing them, but if you are using any resource types which behave in that way then the value stored in the remote system will be lost when you delete the remote object and Terraform won't be able to restore that value because it's not represented in your Terraform configuration.

The `hashicorp/azurerm` provider in particular has many examples of situation 3 in the above list. For example, if you have an `azurerm_virtual_network` resource which does not include any `subnet` blocks then the provider will not propose to delete any existing subnets, even though the configuration says that there should be no subnets. However, if you delete the virtual network and then ask Terraform to recreate it then the Terraform configuration has no record of what subnets were supposed to exist and so it will propose to create a network with no subnets at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any advice on how to go about importing stuff from an existing Azure subscription to minimize the difference? Should I query the list of all resources in a subscription, like subnets, and add them manually?